# Lua alien returning multiple values

Tags: lua, calling-convention

I have this function, i would like to return multiple values but i dont know how to achieve this

```
function GetDiskSpace(_disk)
    require("alien")
    local kernel32 = alien.load("kernel32.dll")
    kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA:types("int", "pointer", "int", "int", "int")

    if kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(_disk, _avail_space, _disk_space, _free_space) ~= 0 then
            return _avail_space, _disk_space, _free_space
            --[[or like this return kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(_disk, _avail_space, _disk_space, _free_space)
            GetDiskFreeSpaceExA should retun non zero if function ran properly, 
            and should retun additional values if those are given 
            (btw values are __int64 i'm not sure if I specified them correct, maybe
            I should set them as "long" instead of "int")
            either way it return only function value and nil's.
            --]]
    else
            print("GetDiskSpace returned error.")
    end
end

hdd_a, hdd_b, hdd_c = GetDiskSpace("C:\\")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type specification you gave is wrong for several reason. The first argument is of type `"string"` and not `"pointer"`. You have to write `"ref int"` and not just `"int"` for a reference (or pointer) to an `int`. And you must also specify the ABI to `"stdcall"`.

When calling the function with a `"ref int"` argument, you pass a dummy 0 value, but get an additional return value, so here `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA` effectively returns 4 results.

You are right to worry about the `uint64_t` value type for the results. As far as I know, Alien **does not** support 64 bit integers, so the following code only returns the 32 lower bits for the disk spaces:

```
function GetDiskSpace(_disk)
    require("alien")
    local kernel32 = alien.load("kernel32.dll")
    kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA:types { ret="int", abi="stdcall", 
        "string", "ref int", "ref int", "ref int" }
    local ok, _avail_space, _disk_space, _free_space = 
        kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(_disk, 0, 0, 0)
    assert(ok == 1, "GetDiskSpace returned error.")
    return _avail_space, _disk_space, _free_space
end

hdd_a, hdd_b, hdd_c = GetDiskSpace("C:\\")
```

To correct this, you can add support for 64 bit integers by modifying the source code of Alien and rebuilding it.